# Retrieving data from two SQL databases in VBA excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have this long SQL query that works fine and I want to run it through Excel VBA to get the data in Excel.

I have spotted two issues to resolve in order to have my query running.

The first one is how you can retrieve data from two SQL databases in VBA Excel and the second one is how temporary tables are handled in VBA.

My working SQL query is

```
/* Layout: Temporary table containing all the information for Charge Events */
/* Layout: Temporary table containing all the information for Discharge Events */
/* Layout: Joining it all together */

/*Declaring the time frame for the data*/ 
   DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(10)
   DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(10)
     
    SET @StartDate ='20/11/2020'
    SET @EndDate ='21/11/2020'

/*Making the temporary table for the Charge data*/

drop table #chargeeventstable   
SELECT  
      [Date1]=  a.[_TimeStamp],[FCE1]='A',
      [Shift]=case when DATEPART(hour, a.[_TimeStamp]) between 7 and 18 then '1' else '2' end ,
      [Avg_Charg_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0')) else null end),
      [Charge_slabs_A]=sum(case when a.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end),    
      [NGVolA]=sum(CASE WHEN a.[Furnace] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (a.[NG_AVG_MEAS_FLOW],'0.0')) else 0.0 end ) ,      
      [FCE2]='B' ,
      [Avg_Charg_Temp_B]=avg(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='B' then convert(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0')) else null end),
      [Charge_slabs_B]=sum(case when a.[FURNACE] ='B' then 1.0 else '0' end),
         
into #chargeeventstable

 FROM (select a.*, (select min(aa.[_TimeStamp])
            from ix.dbo.Fce_Data aa 
            where aa.[_TimeStamp] > a.[_TimeStamp])as next_time_2
    from ix.dbo.Fce_Data a) a 
    Left JOIN ADB.dbo.Temp_Aims b on b.[charge_time] >= a.[_TimeStamp] and b.[charge_time] < a.[next_time_2] and a.[Furnace] = b.[Furnace]
    
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, a.[_TimeStamp], 103)  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 103) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 103)     

Group by a.[_TimeStamp]
ORDER BY a.[_TimeStamp]

/*Making the temporary table for the Discharge data*/
      
drop table #dischargeeventstable    
SELECT  
      [Discharge_slabs_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else '0' end),
      [Discharge_slabs_B]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='B' then 1.0 else '0' end),     

into #dischargeeventstable

 FROM (select a.*, (select min(aa.[_TimeStamp])
            from ix.dbo.Fce_Data aa 
            where aa.[_TimeStamp] > a.[_TimeStamp])as next_time_2
    from ix.dbo.Fce_Data a) a 
    Left JOIN ADB.dbo.Temp_Aims b on b.[discharge_time] >= a.[_TimeStamp] and b.[discharge_time] < a.[next_time_2] and a.[Furnace] = b.[Furnace]

WHERE CONVERT(datetime, a.[_TimeStamp], 103)  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 103) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 103)     

Group by a.[_TimeStamp]
ORDER BY a.[_TimeStamp]

/*Joining the two temporary tables together*/

SELECT 
      [FCE1],
      a.[Date1],
      [Shift],
      [Charge_slabs_A],
      [Avg_Charg_Temp_A],
      [NGVolA], 
      [FCE2],
      [Charge_slabs_B],
      [Avg_Charg_Temp_B],
      [Discharge_slabs_A],
      [Discharge_slabs_B]
       
 FROM #chargeeventstable a 
    Left JOIN #dischargeeventstable b on a.[Date1] = b.[Date1]
```

So pretty much what I want to do is to translate this query into VBA Excel.
What I have done so far in VBA is:

```
Private Sub SetScrollBarRange()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("-Input Data-")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ScrollBarSelDate.Max = LastRow
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBarSelDate_Change()
    SetScrollBarRange
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A&B").Cells(4, 15) = ScrollBarSelDate.Value

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()

    On Error Resume Next
  
    Sheets("Loading").Select
    Sheets("-Input Data-").Range("A20:AQ1000").ClearContents

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cm As New ADODB.Command
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim StartDate As String
    Dim EndDate As String
    StartDate = Sheets("A&B Sankey").Cells(2, 18)
    EndDate = Sheets("A&B Sankey").Cells(2, 20)

      SQLStr = "drop table #chargeeventstable"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "SELECT  [Date1]=  a.[_TimeStamp],[FCE1]='A',[Shift]=case when DATEPART(hour, a.[_TimeStamp]) between 7 and 18 then '1' else '2' end,"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Avg_Charg_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0')) else null end),"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Charge_slabs_A]=sum(case when a.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end),"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[NGVolA]=sum(CASE WHEN a.[Furnace] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (a.[NG_AVG_MEAS_FLOW],'0.0')) else 0.0 end ) ,"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Date1]=  a.[_TimeStamp],[FCE2]='B',[Shift]=case when DATEPART(hour, a.[_TimeStamp]) between 7 and 18 then '1' else '2' end, "
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Avg_Charg_Temp_B]=avg(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='B' then convert(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0')) else null end),"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Charge_slabs_B]=sum(case when a.[FURNACE] ='B' then 1.0 else '0' end)"
     
     SQLStr = SQLStr & " into #chargeeventstable"

SQLStr = SQLStr & " FROM (select a.*, (select min(aa.[_TimeStamp])"
            SQLStr = SQLStr & "from ix.dbo.Fce_Data aa"
            SQLStr = SQLStr & "where aa.[_TimeStamp] > a.[_TimeStamp])as next_time_2"
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "from ix.dbo.Fce_Data a) a"
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "Left JOIN ADB.dbo.Temp_Aims b on b.[charge_time] >= a.[_TimeStamp] and b.[charge_time] < a.[next_time_2] and a.[Furnace] = b.[Furnace]"
    
SQLStr = SQLStr & "WHERE CONVERT(datetime, a.[_TimeStamp], 20)  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 20) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 20)"

SQLStr = SQLStr & "Group by a.[_TimeStamp]"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "ORDER BY a.[_TimeStamp]"
      
  SQLStr = SQLStr & "drop table #dischargeeventstable"

SQLStr = SQLStr & "SELECT"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Date1]=  a.[_TimeStamp],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Discharge_slabs_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else '0' end),"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Avg_DisCharg_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[ave_disch_temp],'0')) else null end),"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Discharge_slabs_B]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='B' then 1.0 else '0' end),"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Avg_DisCharg_Temp_B]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='B' then convert(real,isnull (b.[ave_disch_temp],'0')) else null end)"

SQLStr = SQLStr & "into #dischargeeventstable"

 SQLStr = SQLStr & "FROM (select a.*, (select min(aa.[_TimeStamp])"
            SQLStr = SQLStr & "from ix.dbo.Fce_Data aa"
            SQLStr = SQLStr & "where aa.[_TimeStamp] > a.[_TimeStamp])as next_time_2"
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "from ix.dbo.Fce_Data a) a"
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "Left JOIN ADB.dbo.temp_Aims b on b.[discharge_time] >= a.[_TimeStamp] and b.[discharge_time] < a.[next_time_2] and a.[Furnace] = b.[Furnace]"

SQLStr = SQLStr & "WHERE CONVERT(datetime, a.[_TimeStamp], 20)  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 20) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 20)"

SQLStr = SQLStr & "Group by a.[_TimeStamp]"
SQLStr = SQLStr & "ORDER BY a.[_TimeStamp]"
     
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "SELECT"
      
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[FCE1],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "a.[Date1],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Shift],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Charge_slabs_A],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Avg_Charg_Temp_A],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[NGVolA],  "
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[FCE2],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Charge_slabs_B],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Avg_Charg_Temp_B],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Discharge_slabs_A],"
      SQLStr = SQLStr & "[Discharge_slabs_B]"
       
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "FROM #chargeeventstable a"
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "Left JOIN #dischargeeventstable b on a.[Date1] = b.[Date1]"
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "Left JOIN #slabweightcharged c on a.[Date1]=c.[Date1]"
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "LEFT JOIN #slabweightdischarged d on a.[Date1]=d.[Date1]"

    cn.Open "driver={SQL server}; SERVER=name; UID=user; PWD=pass; DATABASE=;"
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Open SQLStr, cn
    rs.MoveFirst
    i = 20  
    While Not rs.EOF
    
        Sheets("-Input Data-").Cells(i, 2) = rs(0)
        Sheets("-Input Data-").Cells(i, 3) = rs(1)
        
i = i + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs.Close
    cn.Close

    'Clean up
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
    
    Sheets("A&B").Select
    SetScrollBarRange
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
```

My first question is how you can retrieve data from two SQL databases (from the same server) in VBA. As you can see in VBA code i havent found a way to do it .The second questions is how are the temporary tables handled in VBA ? Is QLStr = SQLStr & "into #dischargeeventstable" the correct way to translate it to VBA?
I would appreciate any suggestion or comments.

Comment: Not really seeing a question? Does your code work or not? If not, whats not working?

Comment: @DaleK the SQL code works,  VBA no. My first question is how you can retrieve data from two SQL databases (from the same server) in VBA. As you can see in VBA code i havent found a way to do it .The second questions is how are the temporary tables handled in VBA ? Is QLStr = SQLStr & "into #dischargeeventstable" the correct way to translate it to VBA?

Comment: [edit] that into your question so its clear for people.

Comment: Temporary tables aren't handled in VBA at all, they only exist on the SQL Server. I don't expect your SQL code in VBA to work because there's a lack of whitespace between the lines of code. Also, if you're running this against a newer version of SQL Server consider using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...` syntax or some variant otherwise you'll get errors due to the temp tables not yet existing.

Comment: Do you have the permissions to create stored procedures on the database ?

Comment: @CDP1802 unfortunately I don't have permissions

Comment: I am having trouble getting the last SQL to run as #dischargeeventstable only has fields "Discharge_slabs_A","Discharge_slabs_B" no "Date1". Also the VBA has tables #slabweightcharged and #slabweightdischarged which aren't in the SQL version.

Comment: @CDP1802 the query that i am working now is even bigger than the ones posted above. I had to trim some section down as it would be really difficult for anyone to follow. delete the slabweight parts and use [Date1]=  a.[_TimeStamp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can not create procedures I have put the long SQL statements in functions to remove them from the main vba code. I have also removed the ix.dbo and ADB.dbo prefixes so it runs on a single database. Also changed the temporary tables to global with ##. When the script runs it writes the SQL into the logfile.txt so that you can copy/paste the statement into SQL Management Studio and debug any typos. I have tested the script as far as I can without proper data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub click()

    Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection, oCmd As Object
    Dim rs As Object, sSQL As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, n As Long
    
    ' create log file
    Dim LOGFILE As String
    LOGFILE = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\logfile.txt"
    Dim fs As Object, ts As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(LOGFILE, True)
    
    ' get dates
    Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A&B Sankey")
        StartDate = Format(.Range("R2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        EndDate = Format(.Range("T2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    End With
    
    Set oCon = DbConnect ' connect function
    Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
    ts.writeline "Connected to database: " & oCon.DefaultDatabase
   
    ' create #chargeeventstable
    sSQL = SQL_1(StartDate, EndDate)
    ts.writeline vbCrLf & "--- SQL_1 executing ---" & vbCrLf & sSQL
    
    oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
    oCmd.Execute
    
    ' create #dischargeeventstable
    sSQL = SQL_2(StartDate, EndDate)
    ts.writeline vbCrLf & "--- SQL_2 executing ---" & vbCrLf & sSQL
    
    oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
    oCmd.Execute

    ' SQL_3
    sSQL = " SELECT * " & vbCrLf & _
           " FROM  ##chargeeventstable a" & vbCrLf & _
           " LEFT JOIN ##dischargeeventstable b" & vbCrLf & _
           " ON a.[Date1] = b.[Date1]"
    ts.writeline vbCrLf & "--- SQL_3 executing ---" & vbCrLf & sSQL
           
          '" SELECT [FCE1],a.[Date1],[Shift]," & _
          ' "        [Charge_slabs_A],[Avg_Charg_Temp_A]," & _
          ' "        [NGVolA],[FCE2],[Charge_slabs_B]," & _
          ' "        [Avg_Charg_Temp_B]," & _
          ' "        [Discharge_slabs_A],[Discharge_slabs_B]" & _

    ' execute select
    oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
    Set rs = oCmd.Execute
       
    ' show results
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("-Input Data-")
    ws.Range("B20").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ws.Range("B20").Activate
    
    ' close
    oCon.Close
    ts.Close
    MsgBox "Result written to " & ws.Name & _
           "For " & StartDate & "-" & EndDate, vbInformation, "Finished"

End Sub

Function DbConnect() As ADODB.Connection

    Dim sConn As String
    sConn = "driver={SQL server}; SERVER=name; " & _
            "UID=user; PWD=pass; DATABASE=;"
    
    Set DbConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    DbConnect.Open sConn
    
End Function

Function SQL_1(StartDate As String, EndDate As String) As String

    SQL_1 = _
" DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(10)" & vbCrLf & _
" DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(10)" & vbCrLf & _
" SET @StartDate ='" & StartDate & "'" & vbCrLf & _
" SET @EndDate ='" & EndDate & "'" & vbCrLf

SQL_1 = SQL_1 & _
" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##chargeeventstable   " & vbCrLf & _
" SELECT " & vbCrLf & _
"   [Date1]= a.[_TimeStamp],[FCE1]='A'," & vbCrLf & _
"   [Shift]= CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, a.[_TimeStamp]) " & vbCrLf & _
"               BETWEEN 7 AND 18 THEN '1' " & vbCrLf & _
"               ELSE '2' END ," & vbCrLf & _
"   [Avg_Charg_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='A' " & vbCrLf & _
"               THEN CONVERT(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0')) " & vbCrLf & _
"               ELSE null END)," & vbCrLf & _
"   [Charge_slabs_A]=SUM(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='A' " & vbCrLf & _
"               THEN 1.0 ELSE null END),    " & vbCrLf & _
"   [NGVolA]= SUM(CASE WHEN a.[Furnace] ='A' " & vbCrLf & _
"                THEN CONVERT(real,isnull (a.[NG_AVG_MEAS_FLOW],'0.0')) " & vbCrLf & _
"                ELSE 0.0 END ) ,      " & vbCrLf & _
"   [FCE2]='B' ," & vbCrLf & _
"   [Avg_Charg_Temp_B]=avg(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='B' " & vbCrLf & _
"                THEN CONVERT(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0')) " & vbCrLf & _
"                ELSE null END)," & vbCrLf & _
"   [Charge_slabs_B]=SUM(CASE WHEN a.[FURNACE] ='B' " & vbCrLf & _
"                THEN 1.0 " & vbCrLf & _
"                ELSE '0' END) " & vbCrLf & _
" " & vbCrLf & _
" INTO ##chargeeventstable" & vbCrLf

    SQL_1 = SQL_1 & _
" FROM (select a.*, (SELECT min(aa.[_TimeStamp])" & vbCrLf & _
"     FROM dbo.Fce_Data aa " & vbCrLf & _
"     WHERE aa.[_TimeStamp] > a.[_TimeStamp]) AS next_time_2" & vbCrLf & _
"     FROM dbo.Fce_Data a) a " & vbCrLf & _
"     LEFT JOIN dbo.Temp_Aims b " & vbCrLf & _
"         ON b.[charge_time] >= a.[_TimeStamp] " & vbCrLf & _
"        AND b.[charge_time] < a.[next_time_2] " & vbCrLf & _
"        AND a.[Furnace] = b.[Furnace]" & vbCrLf & _
" " & vbCrLf & _
" WHERE CONVERT(datetime, a.[_TimeStamp], 103)  " & vbCrLf & _
"   BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 103) " & vbCrLf & _
"   AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 103) " & vbCrLf & _
" " & vbCrLf & _
" GROUP by a.[_TimeStamp]" & vbCrLf & _
" ORDER BY a.[_TimeStamp]"

End Function

Function SQL_2(StartDate As String, EndDate As String) As String

    SQL_2 = " DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(10)" & vbCrLf & _
" DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(10)" & vbCrLf & _
" SET @StartDate ='" & StartDate & "'" & vbCrLf & _
" SET @EndDate ='" & EndDate & "'" & vbCrLf

   SQL_2 = SQL_2 & _
" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##dischargeeventstable " & vbCrLf & _
" SELECT [Date1]= a.[_TimeStamp]," & vbCrLf & _
"       [Discharge_slabs_A] = SUM(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' " & vbCrLf & _
"     THEN 1.0 ELSE '0' END)," & vbCrLf & _
"       [Discharge_slabs_B] = SUM(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='B' " & vbCrLf & _
"     THEN 1.0 ELSE '0' END)     " & vbCrLf & _
" INTO ##dischargeeventstable" & vbCrLf

    SQL_2 = SQL_2 & _
" FROM (SELECT a.*, (SELECT min(aa.[_TimeStamp])" & vbCrLf & _
" FROM dbo.Fce_Data aa " & vbCrLf & _
" WHERE aa.[_TimeStamp] > a.[_TimeStamp]) AS next_time_2" & vbCrLf & _
" FROM dbo.Fce_Data a) a " & vbCrLf & _
" LEFT JOIN dbo.Temp_Aims b " & vbCrLf & _
"     ON b.[discharge_time] >= a.[_TimeStamp] " & vbCrLf & _
"    AND b.[discharge_time] < a.[next_time_2] " & vbCrLf & _
"    AND a.[Furnace] = b.[Furnace]" & vbCrLf & _
" " & vbCrLf & _
" WHERE CONVERT(datetime, a.[_TimeStamp], 103) " & vbCrLf & _
" BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 103)" & vbCrLf & _
" AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 103)     " & vbCrLf & _
" " & vbCrLf & _
" GROUP BY a.[_TimeStamp]" & vbCrLf & _
" ORDER BY a.[_TimeStamp]"

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks very much CDP1802 i will run it and let you know about it. I have a silly question though in the Dim sConnect  part you are setting a connection with a specific database(lets say ix.dbo), how it is possible to get data from an other database(ADB.dbo) at the same time?

Comment: @theo13 The connection will have a default database in the connection string that you can use without prefix like SELECT * FROM [table]  but any other database can be accessed or joined to with a fully qualified name like SELECT * FROM [anotherdb].[dbo].[table], providing you have the permissions of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, your approach is what I need .